Chevalley's theorem on valuation spectra
In the paper On Valuation Spectra (Section 2, Page 176), Huber and Knebusch asserted that: if the ring map $A\to B$ is finitely presented then the associated map of valuation spectra $\mathrm{Spv}(B)\to \mathrm{Spv}(A)$ preserves constructible sets. They said that this is an immediate consequence of the fact that the theory of algebraically closed fields with non-trivial valuation-divisibility relation has elimination of quantifiers. Sorry that I am not familiar with model theory, can someone explain this a little bit more in detail (or some references)? I assume that finitely presented is to ensure that $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ preserves constructible sets?
$\textbf{Edit}$: On Page 169 they remarked that:

The model theoretic result that the theory of algebraically closed fields with non-trivial valuation-divisibility relation has elimination of quantifiers implies that the equivalence classes of valuations of $A$ correspond bijectively to the elementary equivalence classes of ring homomorphisms from $A$ to non-trivial valued algebraically closed fields.

So intuitively, it seems that they are claiming that constructible sets in $\mathrm{Spv}(A)$ come from the constructible set in $\mathrm{Spec}(A)(K)$ for some non-trivial valued algebraically closed fields $K$. So Chevalley's theorem for $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ gives Chevalley's theorem for $\mathrm{Spv}(B)\to \mathrm{Spv}(A)$. Does it makes sense?

This is expanded in Huber's seminar notes on the subject as Satz 1.1.21.:

A set $\{v\in \mathrm{Spv}: \mathrm{Frac}(A/\mathrm{supp}(v)),A(v)\models \phi\}$ where $\phi$ is a quantifier-free formula in  the language of fields with the binary relation $a|b$ for $\bar v(a)<\bar v(b)$ is constructible. Here $A(v)$ and $\bar v$ are as in (1.1) of "On Valuation Spectra".
Any constructible set is a union of sets of the form
$$Q:=\{v\in \mathrm{Spv} B:v(h(a_1))<v(h(b_1)),\dots v(h(a_s))<v(h(b_s)),v(h(c_1))\le v(h(d_1)),\dots v(h(c_l))\le v(h(d_l))\}$$
where $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in A[T_1,\dots T_n]$, $B=A[T_1,...T_n]/(p_1,\dots p_m)$ and $h$ is the projection $A[T_1,\dots T_n]\to B$. So it is enough to prove the theorem for such sets.
Now consider a formula in the language of fields from Step 1:
$$\phi:=\exists\bar x( \bar p_1(\bar x)=\dots=\bar p_m(\bar x)=0\land \bar a_1(\bar x)|\bar b_1(\bar x)\land\dots \bar a_s(\bar x)|b_s(\bar x)\land 
\neg (\bar d_1(\bar x)|\bar c_1(\bar x))\land\dots \neg (\bar d_l(\bar x)|\bar c_l(\bar x)))$$
where $\bar x=(x_1,\dots x_n)$ and $\bar p_i,\bar a_i,\bar b_i, \bar c_i,\bar d_i$ are obtained from corresponding polynomials by substituting the coefficients by new variables. Essentially this formula, when evaluated on coefficients of all polynomials involved, says "my valuation belongs to $Q$" (with correspondence $v\to \bar v$ in mind).
By quantifier elimination we know that this formula is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula $\Sigma$.
The image of $Q$ is
$$\{v\in \mathrm{Spv} A:\text{there is an extension of valued fields } (F,B)/(\mathrm{Frac}(A/\mathrm{supp}(v)),A(v)), F\text{ alg. closed},B\neq F , (F,B)\models \phi'\}=$$

$$=\{v\in \mathrm{Spv} A:\text{there is an extension of valued fields } (F,B)/(\mathrm{Frac}(A/\mathrm{supp}(v)),A(v)), F\text{ alg. closed},B\neq F , (F,B)\models \Sigma'\}$$
Since $\Sigma'$ is quantifier-free the latter set is equal to
$$\{v\in \mathrm{Spv} A:(\mathrm{Frac}(A/\mathrm{supp}(v)),A(v))\models \Sigma'\}$$
which is constructible by Step 1. Here $\phi',\Sigma'$ are sentences obtained from formulas $\phi,\Sigma$ by plugging in the images of polynomails involved (originally over $A$) in $\mathrm{Frac}(A/\mathrm{supp}(v))$.

Could you please briefly explain how it works in the third step? I imagine that, if we are only considering equations, this is more or less elimination of variables via resultant, but I do not know what happens with division relations.

@Z.M The quantifier elimination for ACVF is proved on pages 37-39 here:
http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/valued_fields.pdf
(it requires some model theoretic argot and I do not know how to get rid of it, neither can i say that i understand the proof)
